# how to filup the textbox value after popup the bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to fillup textbox value when user select the value from the dropdownlist

but issue is my dropdownlist is coming when click on apply link

see below image when I click the apply button then open bootstrap model

I write the code for change the value of dropdownlist an fillup that value in another textbox

.cshtml

```
          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label>Vacancy:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <select id="hm" class="form-control">

                                    @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.vacancy)
                                    {
                                        <option value="item.vacancytitle">
                                            @item.vacancytitle
                                        </option>
                                    }
                                </select>

                             
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <br />

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label>vacancyid:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="vacancyid" value="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
          <div>
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $('#applylink').click(function () {

        debugger

        //var h = document.getElementById(hm).value;
        //var strUser = h.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        //$('#vacancyid').val(strUser);


        $("#myModal").modal();  //here open bootstrap modal

        $('#hm').on('change', function () {
            var selectVal = $("#selectId option:selected").val();
            $('#vacancyid').val(selectVal);    //here I am trying to fetch value from dropdownlist when user select the particular value from the dropdownlist
        });

    });

</script>
```

currently I have two value in dropdownlist

```
html/css developer
angular,js developer
```

when user select `html/css developer` from the dropdownlist then here I am filling

```
 $('#vacancyid').val(selectVal);
```

html/css developer

first click the apply link button and then open bootstrap modal

I want to fillup textbox value when user select the value from the dropdownlist

[image]

when open the popup then I want to call this method

```
$('#hm').on('change', function () {
            var selectVal = $("#selectId option:selected").val();
            $('#vacancyid').val(selectVal);    //here I am trying to fetch value from dropdownlist when user select the particular value from the dropdownlist
        });
```

Edit:

```
        //load javascript after modal is loaded
        //load option value chage after modal is loaded
        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger
            $('#myModal').on('load', function () {
                debugger
                $('#hm').on('change', function () {   //debugger here not come when select the value from the dropdownlist
                    debugger
                    var selectVal = $("#selectId option:selected").val();
                    $('#vacancyid').val(selectVal);
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Where is your Modal HTML ?

Comment: Where is the textbox you want to fill when user selects the option ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping https://i.stack.imgur.com/TogPY.png see this image I am store the dropdown change value in textbox

Comment: you want to add the dropdown change value in the `vacancyid` input which is is below it ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping my data is not static that is main issue

Comment: that's not an issue - that can be solved - please tell me you want to add the `dropdown` change value in the `vacancyid` input which is is below it

Comment: @AlwaysHelping yes ```function cevent() {

        debugger
        var selectVal = $("#hm option:selected").val();
        $('#vacancyid').val(selectVal);
    }```

Comment: see this change dropdownlist event code ```<select id="hm" class="form-control" onchange="cevent()">
                                    @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.vacancy)
                                    {
                                        <option value="item.vacancytitle">
                                            @item.vacancytitle
                                        </option>
                                    }
                                </select>```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222072/discussion-between-aayushi-babariya-and-always-helping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the native `BS` function like `shown.bs.modal`. Your load function is not doing anything when the modal shows so your change function is not working at all.

Also, since you want load the `vacancyId` value from dropdown- You can simply assign the option the value of `@item.vacancyId`

```
<select id="hm" class="form-control">

  @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.vacancy)
  {
  <option value="@item.vacancyid">
    @item.vacancytitle
  </option>
  }
</select>
```

Load the boostrap modal like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#hm').on('change', function() {
      var selectVal = $(this).val();
      $('#vacancyid').val(selectVal);
    }); //this method work now :)
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use show event for bootstrap modal. See [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events).

Like as in the following code:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
// your code goes here
})
```

Comment: thanks for answer ```'shown.bs.modal' ``` here I am using ```load``` that is not work I change it now work fine

Comment: Great , Thanks for confirming